# Returning two values from a method

Tags: java, output

I am trying to implement a method that takes two boolean parameters, uses these inputs and outputs two results. I tried to create another class that holds the two results but I got confused in the way of returning the two results. This is my attempt so far:

```
public class Results 
{
    private boolean Sum;
    private boolean Carry;

    public Results  (boolean Sum, boolean Carry)
    {
        this.Sum = Sum;
        this.Carry = Carry;
    }

    public boolean getSum()
    {
        return Sum;
    }

    public void setSum(boolean sum)
    {
        this.Sum = sum;
    }

    public boolean getCarry()
    {
        return Carry;
    }

    public void setCarry(boolean carry)
    {
        this.Carry = carry;
    }
}
```

This is my function:

```
public Results(boolean inp1, boolean inp2)
{
    boolean sum = x1.OperatorGate(inp1, inp2);
    boolean carry = a1.OperatorGate(inp1, inp2);
    return new Results(sum, carry);  
}
```

I know that there are a lot of examples on this site of how to achieve this, but every example I found, didn't use any parameters in the function.

Comment: it looks right to me. What's the question?

Comment: That's not a function, it's a constructor.  Try giving your function a name.

Comment: That looks like a constructor, not a function... I imagine what your looking for is something like  public Results getResults() { return this; }

Comment: @MarkW That depends on whether `getResults` is inside `Results` or not.  And if it's inside `Results`, adding a function that just returns `this` is redundant noise.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I did a silly mistake. I implemented a constructor not a function

Comment: Just my opinion: If you're writing a little class like this whose **only** purpose is to carry two or more pieces of data around, and doesn't represent some more important "concept", it's OK to define it with public member fields, and don't bother with all the getters and setters.  That's the _only_ time I ever use public data members.

Comment: Just because the OP made a mistake due to imperfect understanding of the language, is that a reason to downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Creating a class to hold your set of two responses is correct.

Your function (method in java) is a bit off though.  Try this:

```
public Results getResults(boolean inp1, boolean inp2)
        {
            boolean sum = x1.OperatorGate(inp1, inp2);
            boolean carry = a1.OperatorGate(inp1, inp2);
            return new Results(sum, carry);         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a little confused between the purpose of a Constructor and the difference between a Constructor and a regular-old method that creates an instance of a class and returns it.

One key difference is that a constructor can only be specified inside the definition of its own class - you already did this, which is good.

Another key difference is that when you tried to declare a 'normal' method, you meant to say that the method should return an object of type Results, but instead you named the method Results.  Only a constructor has a name identical to that of a class it is creating.  So your 'return' statement does belong there, you just need to change the first line of your method declaration.